# How do I get timestamps in logfile of pexpect

Tags: python, python-2.7, pexpect

I am using **pexpect** to handle my telnet and ssh communication.
I am also writing all request/response in a **logfile**. using `pexpect.logfile(filename)`.

I would like to have **timestamps** in the logfile as well.
I can not find it anywhere in the documentation! Does anyone have any idea how to implement this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching I found the below code which works for me!
Take a look at the below code:

```
import logging
import pexpect
import re

# this is the method called by the pexpect object to log
def _write(*args, **kwargs):
    content = args[0]
    # Ignore other params, pexpect only use one arg
    if content in [' ', '', '\n', '\r', '\r\n']:
        return # don't log empty lines
    for eol in ['\r\n', '\r', '\n']:
        # remove ending EOL, the logger will add it anyway
        content = re.sub('\%s$' % eol, '', content)
    return logger.info(content) # call the logger info method with the reworked content

# our flush method
def _doNothing():
    pass

logger = logging.getLogger('foo')
hdlr = logging.FileHandler('/bar.log')
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(hdlr)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# give the logger the methods required by pexpect
logger.write = _write
logger.flush = _doNothing

p = pexpect.spawn('echo "hello world !"', logfile=logger)
```

Comment: This is great for adding timestamps (I tried it and it works). However, I had switched from using `p.logfile` to `p.logfile_read` to avoid logging the passwords used to send to my pexpect ssh commands. This `logger` method prints the passwords to the logfile. How do I retain the `log_read` functionality while moving to this `logger` method?

Answer (score 6):

`logfile` can be any object that has `write()`, `flush()` methods:

```
from datetime import datetime

class TimestampedFile(object):
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file

    def write(self, data):
        # .. filter data however you like
        ts = datetime.utcnow().isoformat()  # generate timestamp
        return self.file.write("%s %s\n" % (ts, data))  # write to original file

    def flush(self):
        self.file.flush()
```

#### Example

```
with open(filename, 'w') as file:
    pexpect.run('echo "hello world!"', logfile=TimestampedFile(file))
```

[Your logging example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13289161/4279) could be simplified:

```
class FileAdapter(object):
    def __init__(self, logger):
        self.logger = logger
    def write(self, data):
        # NOTE: data can be a partial line, multiple lines
        data = data.strip() # ignore leading/trailing whitespace
        if data: # non-blank
           self.logger.info(data)
    def flush(self):
        pass  # leave it to logging to flush properly
```

#### Example

```
# setup logging to include a timestamp
logging.basicConfig(format="%(asctime)s %(message)s", level=logging.INFO)
# ... run command sometime later
pexpect.run('echo "hello world!"', logfile=FileAdapter(logging.getLogger('foo')))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the [pexpect.py](http://pexpect.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pexpect/trunk/pexpect/pexpect.py?revision=533&view=markup) source file, you'll see that the approach taken to logging is simply writing what is sent/received to the child process to a stream (which can be a file or, for example, `sys.stdout` if you prefer to log to the console). Therefore what you asked for is impossible without changing the `pexpect` sources, to for example, be able to use a standard library [logging](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module logger for output (hint: maybe a good opportunity to contribute an enhancement to the project?).