# A minor clarification on the program below

Tags: python

I took this example from one of the stack flow thread.. 
[How do I get timestamps in logfile of pexpect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13271686/how-do-i-get-timestamps-in-logfile-of-pexpect)

on this code, the call is being made to the user defined functions _write and _doNothing from Logger class.

```
import logging
import pexpect
import re

# this is the method called by the pexpect object to log
def _write(*args, **kwargs):
    content = args[0]
    # Ignore other params, pexpect only use one arg
    if content in [' ', '', '\n', '\r', '\r\n']:
        return # don't log empty lines
    for eol in ['\r\n', '\r', '\n']:
        # remove ending EOL, the logger will add it anyway
        content = re.sub('\%s$' % eol, '', content)
    return logger.info(content) # call the logger info method with the reworked content

# our flush method
def _doNothing():
    pass

logger = logging.getLogger('foo')
hdlr = logging.FileHandler('/bar.log')
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(hdlr)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# give the logger the methods required by pexpect
logger.write = _write
logger.flush = _doNothing

p = pexpect.spawn('echo "hello world !"', logfile=logger)
```

the logger class does not have these methods. just wondering how these calls being made? can someone pls explain so that i can get a better understanding?

Comment: I guess you're referring to the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13289161/21028 ? You should rewrite your question to include that code, as right now this is not a self-contained question. The functions there are defined, and one merely changes the logger functions to use them instead.

Comment: Yes. just wondering how are the user_defined functions getting called from the logger?

Comment: @csl I tried calling by having my own user defined function but could not. i guess it has something to do with this line p = pexpect.spawn('echo "hello world !"', logfile=logger) which i dont understand. can you pls help me to understand.  when i had my own function, i got the following error msg.Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "logger.py", line 38, in <module>
    logger._myOwnMethod()
AttributeError: 'Logger' object has no attribute '_myOwnMethod'
[root@n3k-qa-auto featurelib]#

Comment: You need to post the specific code that you can't get working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`logger.write` and `logger.flush` are simple aliases to the user defined functions `_write()` and `_doNothing()` respectively in the same module. Imagine a simplified scenario,

```
# User defined function
>>> def _write():
...    print 'Inside _write()'

# Sample Logger class
>>> class Logger:
...    pass

# Object of type Logger
>>> logger = Logger()

# Simply adding a new attribute 'write' to the object 'logger'
# and point to the user defined function name.
# This will create an alias.
>>> logger.write = _write
>>> logger.write()
Inside _write()

# Proof that both 'logger.write' and '_write' are indeed 
# same 
>>> id(logger.write) == id(_write)
```

In nutshell, there is no `_write()` in the `Logger` class, however, you can still create attributes to the object and assign them the alias to refer the user defined function.

**This is exactly what is happening in the code above.**

Comment: Thanks Pankaj.. Now got it.

Comment: Glad to know, that is was useful!

Answer (score 1):

Continuing Pankaj's answer (which is correct), you can even bind `self` in free functions by using `types.MethodType`:

```
import types

class Foo:
    def _print(self, msg):
        print("_print(self=%s, msg='%s')" % (self, msg))

    def hello(self, name):
        self._print("Hello, %s!" % name)

def my_print(self, msg):
    print("my_print(self=%s, msg='%s')" % (self, msg))

# Normal call
foo = Foo()
foo.hello("foobar")

# Swap _print with my_print, binding it to a method so you can use `self`
foo._print = types.MethodType(my_print, foo, Foo)
foo.hello("foobar")
```

which prints:

```
_print(self=<__main__.Foo instance at 0x7f958e772098>, msg='Hello, foobar!')
my_print(self=<__main__.Foo instance at 0x7f958e772098>, msg='Hello, foobar!')
```